# Join 3 related tables mySql

Tags: mysql, join

I want to join the following tables and display them in table on a page.

Table 1
•   carID
•   car_name
•   reg_name
•   price

Table 2
•   userID
•   first_name
•   last_name
•   email_address
•   province
•   address

Table 3
•   orderID
•   userID
•   car_ID
•   notes
•   date

I want to display all the fields on a php page. I am only able to join two tables and I am unable to link the third table.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join).

```
SELECT * FROM table3,table2,table1 
    WHERE table2.userID=table3.userID AND table1.carID=table3.carID
```

Comment: and where;s the join here exactly?!

Comment: Cross join "table3,table2,table1".

Comment: Thank you Elliot... it is actually pretty simple :-)

Comment: That's not a cross join. That's an implicit INNER JOIN. I would advise on writing them in the explicit way

Answer (score 0):

Use [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html)

```
SELECT *
FROM table3
JOIN table1 ON table1.carID = table3.carID
JOIN table2 ON table2.userID = table3.userID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT tb1.carId, tb1.reg_name, tb1.price, tb2.userId, tb2.first_name, 
tb2.last_name, tb2.email_address, tb2.province, tb2.address,
tb3.orderId, tb3.notes, tb3.date
FROM Table1 tb1
INNER JOIN Table3 tb3 ON Tb1.carID = tb3.carID
INNER JOIN Table2 tb3 ON tb3.userID = tb2.userID
```